# Docker event output formatting

Tags: events, docker, format

Is there an easy way to format the output from the `docker events` into something thats more easily parseable ? I need to extract the event and the container name and was hoping there would be an easy way to get to this without having to use regex's

```
2016-03-09T01:40:02.466829474Z container die 0dc47eaf33002354222eb871471c36793c6df22589bec15da9ba9e570e1e7d62 (image=injcristianrojas/nginx-ssl, name=nginx-ssl)
2016-03-09T01:40:02.634452427Z container start 0dc47eaf33002354222eb871471c36793c6df22589bec15da9ba9e570e1e7d62 (image=injcristianrojas/nginx-ssl, name=nginx-ssl)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the below command

```
docker events --filter 'type=container' --format 'Type={{.Type}} Status={{.Status}} Name={{.Actor.Attributes.name}} Time={{.Time}}'
```

Comment: Where did you find which fields are available? The documentation lacks this information :(

Comment: @PetrÚjezdský It's been 2 years but to get the available fields export the output as json, you will find all the field names: `docker events --format '{{json .}}'`

Answer (score 1):

Events can be returned in [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format using the `--format` option of the [`events`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/events/) Docker command.  The relevant portions of the event can then be parsed out using tools that operate on JSON.

```
docker events --format '{{json .}}'
```

Output JSON (reformatted and with only relevant data for readability):

```json
{
  "status": "start",
  "id": "0dc47eaf33002354222eb871471c36793c6df22589bec15da9ba9e570e1e7d62",
  "Type": "container",
  "Action": "start",
  "Actor": {
    "ID": "0dc47eaf33002354222eb871471c36793c6df22589bec15da9ba9e570e1e7d62",
    "Attributes": {
      "image": "injcristianrojas/nginx-ssl",
      "name": "nginx-ssl",
    }
  },
  "time": 1457487602,
  "timeNano": 1457487602466142756
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly the remote json based API: [Docker remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/)

```
curl http://localhost:5555/events
{"status":"kill","id":"b3167fc9fce425786710cc06a51320f01743bfe56ec9f198edeecdfa4d0a6","from":"nginx","time":1457519533}
{"status":"die","id":"b3167fc9fce425786710cc06a51320f01743bfe56ec9f198edeecdfa4d0a6","from":"nginx","time":1457519535}
```

Comment: Thats what I thought. I'm using Kitematic and trying this. `curl --no-buffer -XGET --unix-socket tcp://192.168.99.102:2376 http:/events` but I can't get it to connect.

Comment: Port 2376 use tls authentication. You need to load certificates with your request: `curl --insecure --cert $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/cert.pem --key $DOCKER_CERT_PATH/key.pem https://YOUR_VM_IP:2376/images/json`

Comment: This is not working on macosx for me. A workaround here (not tested): http://blog.arungupta.me/enable-docker-remote-api-mac-osx-machine/